# How to PInvoke GetVirtualDiskInformation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

**Full minimalist (non-working) code**: http://pastebin.com/GPdSxyrt

I'm trying to PInvoke GetVirtualDiskInformation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323670(v=vs.85).aspx) and have my code as such:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct GetVirtualDiskInfo
{
    public GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion Version; //GET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO_VERSION
    public GetVirtualDiskInfoUnion Union;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoSize Size;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid Identifier; //GUID
    [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoParentLocation ParentLocation;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid ParentIdentifier; //GUID
    [FieldOffset(0)] public uint ParentTimestamp; //ULONG
    [FieldOffset(0)] public VirtualStorageType VirtualStorageType; //VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE
    [FieldOffset(0)] public uint ProviderSubtype; //ULONG
    [FieldOffset(0)] public bool Is4kAligned; //BOOL
    [FieldOffset(0)] public bool IsLoaded; //BOOL
    [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoPhysicalDisk PhysicalDisk;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public uint VhdPhysicalSectorSize; //ULONG
    [FieldOffset(0)] public ulong SmallestSafeVirtualSize; //ULONGLONG
    [FieldOffset(0)] public uint FragmentationPercentage; //ULONG
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid VirtualDiskId; //GUID
    [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoChangeTrackingState ChangeTrackingState;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoSize
{
    public ulong VirtualSize; //ULONGLONG
    public ulong PhysicalSize; //ULONGLONG
    public uint BlockSize; //ULONG
    public uint SectorSize; //ULONG
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoParentLocation
{
    public bool ParentResolved; //BOOL
    public char ParentLocationBuffer; //WCHAR[1] //TODO
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoPhysicalDisk
{
    public uint LogicalSectorSize; //ULONG
    public uint PhysicalSectorSize; //ULONG
    public bool IsRemote; //BOOL
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoChangeTrackingState
{
    public bool Enabled; //BOOL
    public bool NewerChanges; //BOOL
    public char MostRecentId; //WCHAR[1] //TODO
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct VirtualStorageType
{
    public VirtualStorageDeviceType DeviceId; //ULONG
    public Guid VendorId; //GUID
}

public enum GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion
{
    Unspecified = 0,
    Size = 1,
    Identifier = 2,
    ParentLocation = 3,
    ParentIdentifier = 4,
    ParentTimestamp = 5,
    VirtualStorageType = 6,
    ProviderSubtype = 7,
    Is4KAligned = 8,
    PhysicalDisk = 9,
    VhdPhysicalSectorSize = 10,
    SmallestSafeVirtualSize = 11,
    Fragmentation = 12,
    IsLoaded = 13,
    VirtualDiskId = 14,
    ChangeTrackingState = 15
}

public enum VirtualStorageDeviceType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Iso = 1,
    Vhd = 2,
    Vhdx = 3,
    Vhdset = 4
}

[DllImport("virtdisk.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint GetVirtualDiskInformation
(
    [In]            VirtualDiskSafeHandle virtualDiskHandle,
    [In, Out]   ref uint virtualDiskInfoSize,
    [In, Out]   ref GetVirtualDiskInfo virtualDiskInfo,
    [In, Out]   ref uint sizeUsed
);
```

And I'm calling GetVirtualDiskInformation like so:

```
var info = new GetVirtualDiskInfo {Version = infoVersion};
infoSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(info);
var result = NativeMethods.GetVirtualDiskInformation(handle, ref infoSize, ref info, ref sizeUsed);
```

Obviously `handle` does contain a valid `VirtualDiskSafeHandle` here.

The problem with this is that my out struct is all screwed up. The data is all over the place. According to it the VHD's `LogicalSectorSize` is 257 for example, and it has a negative `VirtualSize`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get this to work properly?

**EDIT**:

A concrete example of what is going wrong:

I created a brand new VHDX as differencing (no parent, no source), set its max size to 50MB, `LogicalSectorSize` to 512, `PhysicalSectorSize` to 4096, `BlockSize` to 2MB and it's `VendorId` (GUID) to `new Guid("EC984AEC-A0F9-47e9-901F-71415A66345B")`. It has never been attached, it's size on disk stands at exactly 4096KB.

I would expect that when performing:

```
var info = new GetVirtualDiskInfo {Version = GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion.Size};
infoSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(info);
var result = NativeMethods.GetVirtualDiskInformation(handle, ref infoSize, ref info, ref sizeUsed);
```

That `info.Union.Size` would return:

```
VirtualSize = 52428800
PhysicalSize = 4194304
BlockSize = 2097152
SectorSize = 512
```

What I get is "close enough". All values are correct with the exception of `VirtualSize`, which returns 52428801. Now the extra one byte could be something that is expected, but I doubt it. Regardless, the next couple of examples produces far worse results:

```
var info = new GetVirtualDiskInfo {Version = GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion.VirtualStorageType};
infoSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(info);
var result = NativeMethods.GetVirtualDiskInformation(handle, ref infoSize, ref info, ref sizeUsed);
```

Expected results for `info.Union.VirtualStorageType`:

```
DeviceId = 2 //2 Symbolizes VHDX, which is how I created it
VendorId = "EC984AEC-A0F9-47e9-901F-71415A66345B" //As a GUID
```

Actual results:

```
DeviceId = 257
VendorId = "EC984AEC-A0F9-47e9-901F-71415A66345B" //As a GUID
```

In other words, the GUID is fine, the DeviceId is not. 257 is not even a valid value.

Last example:

```
var info = new GetVirtualDiskInfo {Version = GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion.PhysicalDisk};
infoSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(info);
var result = NativeMethods.GetVirtualDiskInformation(handle, ref infoSize, ref info, ref sizeUsed);
```

Expected `info.Union.PhysicalDisk` to return:

```
LogicalSectorSize = 512
PhysicalSectorSize = 4096
IsRemote = false
```

Actual results:

```
LogicalSectorSize  = 257
PhysicalSectorSize = 512
IsRemote = false
```

So again the very first value is completely wrong. 257 is not an accepted value, second value is also wrong, I'd expect 4096.

**EDIT2** ADded VirtualStorageDeviceType to initial code.

**EDIT3** Full example here: http://pastebin.com/GPdSxyrt

**EDIT4**

I worked out that the problem is with the fields that in C are WCHAR[1]. If I comment out the `ChangeTrackingState` in the struct `GetVirtualDiskInfoUnion`, then things work just fine.

Still, I'm not sure what to set them as in C#, they don't appear to be `char` nor `IntPtr` from what I tried, so what does that translate to exactly?

Comment: there is a problem with your struct `GetVirtualDiskInfoUnion`, all the fields are at the offset 0 (`FieldOffset(0)`), i suggest you to replace the zeros by the correct offsets to see if it works

Comment: @bob1024 The correct offsets are 0. It's representing a union in C, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is exactly what I have done. The union is set as explicit!

Comment: Yes. I mis read. What does the error checking tell you? What does the function call return. Also what is infoVersion?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is no error, just the data returned is not correct. intoVersion is what you'd like to query, it's just an enum of type `GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion`. The reason why in native there is that union is because you need to pick what you want to query, it doesn't give you all information at the same time. infoVersion get mapped to `GetVirtualDiskInfo.Version`

Comment: You don't inspect the return value of `GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion`. How can you tell that there's no error? What I'd like to know is what value `infoVersion` has. Which enum value are you passing?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ohh, I've tried passing pretty much all possible values on the enum. Some of them return correct values (by chance? no idea!) others not so much. Do you mean the return value of `GetVirtualDiskInformation`, not `GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion`? If so, it returns 0 (success)

Comment: If it returns zero then it succeeded. Do you understand that since values are overlaid, only fields related to the value of the `GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion` can be expected to have meaning. If you would provide an [MCVE] and a specification of what enum you pass, what values are returned, and what values you expect, it would be a lot easier for us.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan just provided clear examples of what it is returning and what I'd expect it to return. As for your question, I do understand the values are overlaid and I am only reading the values that I query through `GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion`.

Comment: We cannot see `VirtualStorageDeviceType`. I'm getting a little frustrated here. Can't we have a [mcve]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114333/discussion-between-cogumel0-and-david-heffernan).

Answer (score 0):

i do not have solution but noticed that if you add any uint field as last in structure it is also working correctly. My definition is:

public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoUnion

        {

            [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoSize Size;

            [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid Identifier; //GUID

            [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoParentLocation ParentLocation;

            [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid ParentIdentifier; //GUID

            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint ParentTimestamp; //ULONG

            [FieldOffset(0)] public VirtualStorageType VirtualStorageType; //VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE

            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint ProviderSubtype; //ULONG

            [FieldOffset(0)] public bool Is4kAligned; //BOOL

            [FieldOffset(0)] public bool IsLoaded; //BOOL

            [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoPhysicalDisk PhysicalDisk;

            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint VhdPhysicalSectorSize; //ULONG

            [FieldOffset(0)] public ulong SmallestSafeVirtualSize; //ULONGLONG

            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint FragmentationPercentage; //ULONG

            [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid VirtualDiskId; //GUID

            [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoChangeTrackingState ChangeTrackingState;

            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint Reserved; //ULONG

        }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the union starts at 8 (due to alignment)
so you should change the structure to this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct GetVirtualDiskInfo
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion Version; //GET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO_VERSION
    [FieldOffset(8)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoUnion Union;
}
```

As an alternative you can also put all items of the union into the main structure, with all having `[FieldOffset(8)]` instead of `[FieldOffset(0)]`